# Removing records from a store using an AJAX proxy in Sencha Touch 1.1

Tags: ajax, sencha-touch

I don't know how to detect whether an AJAX proxy generated HTTP request is an insert/update or a delete operation.

These are my data (simpsons.json):

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "Homer"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "firstName": "Marge"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "firstName": "Bart"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "firstName": "Lisa"
    }
]
```

This is my Sencha Touch 1.1 code:

```
Character = Ext.regModel('Character', {
    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'firstName', type: 'string'}
    ]
});

SimpsonsStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'Character',
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'simpsons.json'
    },
    autoLoad: true
});

SimpsonsStore.on('load', function(store, records, success) {

    // add record
    store.add({id: 5, firstName: 'Maggie'});

    // update record
    var margeRecord = store.findRecord('firstName', 'Marge');
    margeRecord.set('firstName', 'Marjorie');

    // delete record
    var homerRecord = store.findRecord('firstName', 'Homer');
    store.remove(homerRecord);

    // sync store
    store.sync();
});
```

Running this code generates these HTTP requests:

```
POST /simpsons.json/5?_dc=1321377134028 HTTP/1.1

{"records":[{"id":5,"firstName":"Maggie"}]}
```

.

```
PUT /simpsons.json/2?_dc=1321377142625 HTTP/1.1

{"records":[{"id":2,"firstName":"Marjorie"}]}
```

.

```
DELETE /simpsons.json/1?_dc=1321377148457 HTTP/1.1

{"records":[{"id":1,"firstName":"Homer"}]}
```

Like it, each operation has its own HTTP request method (verb).

When I change the proxy type from "rest" to "ajax" the generated HTTP requests look like these:

```
POST /simpsons.json?_dc=1321376787918 HTTP/1.1

{"records":[{"id":5,"firstName":"Maggie"}]}
```

.

```
POST /simpsons.json?_dc=1321376792207 HTTP/1.1

{"records":[{"id":2,"firstName":"Marjorie"}]}
```

.

```
POST /simpsons.json?_dc=1321376798158 HTTP/1.1

{"records":[{"id":1,"firstName":"Homer"}]}
```

As you can see these look very similar. This is not an issue for insert or update operations. But **how can the backend detect that the last HTTP request is** neither an insert nor an update but **a delete action**?

I found an "api" config option in Sencha Touch 2.0 as it exists in Ext JS 4, but I didn't find a way to define different URLs or parameters for the particular actions of an AJAX proxy in Sencha Touch 1.1.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,

Uwe

Answer (score 2):

Go here http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.data.AjaxProxy scroll down to Url generation, and read about the `Ext.data.Operation` objects and how to use them.

Comment: Thanks. I already read this. All these examples show is how to pass such a custom operation as a parameter to the proxy's read method. But I'm working with a store, calling its sync method. I can't see how these examples could help my to make the generated HTTP requests distinct according to their action. Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

The actionMethods property of the AjaxProxy is set by default to

```
{create: "POST", read: "GET", update: "POST", destroy: "POST"}
```

You can simply overwrite it:

```
store.getProxy().actionMethods = {
    create: "POST",
    read: "GET",
    update: "PUT",
    destroy: "DELETE"
};
```